# The norm of a block Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices, block-matrices, matrix-norms

I have a question about the computation of the norm of a block matrices.

The square block matrix $T_{n}$ is defined as:

\begin{bmatrix}
A_{1,1} &. &.&&A_{1,n} \\
A_{2,1} &. &.&.&A_{2,n}\\
. &. &.&.&.\\
. &. &.&.&.\\
. &. &.&.&.\\
A_{n,1} &. &.&.&A_{n,n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
where $A_{i,j}$ is a $c \times c$ Toeplitz matrix given as
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{0} &a_{1} &.&.&a_{c} \\
a_{-1} &a_{0} &a_{1}&.&.\\
. &. &.&.&.\\
. &. &.&.&a_{1}\\
a_{-c} &. &.&a_{-1}&a_{0}\\
\end{bmatrix}

I would like to compute the following norm

$||T_{n}||^{2}=\underset{x}{\max}(x'T_{n}T'_{n}x)/(x'x)$.

In the case of a simple $n \times n$ Toeplitz matrix, it is easy and gives

$||T_{n}||^{2}=\underset{x}{\max}(x'T_{n}T'_{n}x)/(x'x)=    \sum \limits_{\underset{}{k=0}}^{n-1}\sum \limits_{\underset{}{j=0}}^{n-1} t_{k-j}x'x /(\sum \limits_{\underset{}{k=0}}^{n-1} |x_{k}|^{2})$

Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: To be clear, the $'$ means transpose?

Comment: @Semiclassical yes.